# Unexpected JQuery behaviour when accessing dynamically generated elements by class

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery code that dynamically generates some checkboxes:

```
var container = $('#checkbox_list_container');
var html = '<input type="checkbox" class="selection_checkboxes" name="ids[]" value="1" />';
container.append($(html));
```

I also have the following code that pops up an alert when any of these checkboxes are clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.selection_checkboxes').click(function() {

   alert('click detected');

   if ($(this).attr('checked'))
   {
     if ($('.selection_checkboxes:checked').size() > 3)
     {
       alert('You can only select up to 3 items');     
       return false;
     }
   }
 });
});
```

For some reason, JQuery is unable to detect when any of the dynamically generated checkboxes have been clicked on and display the alert('click detected') message, let alone get a count of all the checked checkboxes with the same class name.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's `live` to attach handlers to dynamically created elements:

```
$('.selection_checkboxes').live('click', function() {
    //stuff
});
```

If all your checkboxes are in `#checkbox_list_container`, then `delegate` is more efficient:

```
$('#checkbox_list_container').delegate('.selection_checkboxes', 'click', function() {
    //stuff
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/